# terminal messing up stick figure drawing

Tags: python, string

Im making a python program that plays hangman and for the incorrect answers I have several different strings that are "Drawings" of the stickfigure that look something like this

```
"""_______           
  |
  |     O
  |    /|\
  |   / | \
  |    / \
  |   /   \
  |
  -----------"""
```

But when it is actually run in the terminal it distorts the image a lot such that its virtually unrecognizable. how do I fix this

Comment: Use a monospaced font

Answer (score 1):

Use a raw string:

```
r"""_______           
  |
  |     O
  |    /|\
  |   / | \
  |    / \
  |   /   \
  |
  -----------"""
```

The problem is that otherwise the backslashes at the end of a line are interpreted as line continuation marker.